# Jacobi symbol: number theory

Tags: number-theory

What is Jacobi symbol of $(-2p^2/4a^2 + p^2)^l$ where $p$ is congruent to $3 mod 4$, $a$ is odd and $l$ is even?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean $$\Big(\frac{-2p^2}{4a^2 + p^2}\Big)^l$$
Since $l$ is even the value is either $1$ or $0$. It is $0$ if
$\gcd(2p^2, 4a^2 + p^2) \ne 1$. Since $4a^2 + p^2$ is odd a non-zero GCD will be a multiple of $p$, i.e. $\gcd(2a, p) = p$. And because $a$ shall be odd you must have  $a=(2n+1)p, \; n \in \mathbb{Z}$.